# 404 Pages and 301 redirect

Tags: http-status-code-404

We built pages like this:

Old URL:
http://www.ifsc-code.co.in/all-india-banks-database/bank-of-india/karnataka/
Please notice, bank of india is the bank name and karnataka is the state name.

New URL:
http://bank-of-india.ifsc-code.co.in/karnataka

There are 45000 old urls all have been set as 301 redirect to new url. Its been 2 months, but still google sees them as 404. Why?

This is how Googlebot fetched the page.

```
URL: http:/ /www.ifsc-code.co.in/all-india-banks-database/bank-of-india/karnataka/

Date: Thursday, March 29, 2012 1:29:54 PM PDT

Googlebot Type: Web

Download Time (in milliseconds): 168

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 29 Mar 2012 20:29:54 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 DAV/2 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.8
Location: http:/ /bank-of-india.ifsc-code.co.in/karnataka
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
```

Then why does this page shows up in 404 page? The url that links to that page doesn't even exist, which is also a 301 redirect.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have to manually mark them as fixed in webmaster tools : [Mark crawl error as fixed](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35120)